# The fuction of を in this specific sentence

Tags: usage, particle-を

I was reading this short 小説 about a difficult love relationship bewteen a man and a woman, and this sentences show up.

叶わない恋は存在するとは思います。
でも、二人が望んでいるなら、
超えられる事**を**多くあると信じています。

So, despite be able to understand the general meaning, i don't quite get the fuction of を in the last sentence; for my understanding, it should be:

でも、二人が望んでいるなら
超えられる事**が**多くあると信じています。

With と as a quotation mark.
を indicates a direct object of a verb, but here what is the verb? ある is an intransitive verb, so it cannot takes direct object; 信じている may be, but then what is the use of と if it's not a quotation mark?
Could you help me understand? Thank you very much!

P.S. I know that を can be use not only for direct object, but also to express a movement through a place or something. Is this the case? Perhaps, figuratively?

Comment: It must be a typo. Most naturally it is も or は, or perhaps が.

Comment: That's very interesting. I would've totally expected a が

Comment: So i'm not the only one who questioning about this usage ahahah. I too would expected a が or a は, but not a を. I can think only on the "movement through a place", figuratively.

Comment: I wonder if this is an editing artifact?  Perhaps in an earlier version of the text, the ～を phrase had a different verb after it, and through successive cuts and reworkings, the author and/or editors arrived at the above, with the を forgotten and leftover, and now out of place.

Comment: Honestly, i don't know. I read this text on a website and not on paper, so it may be that in final version a forgotten particle reamain or something like you said. But thanks for the comment! I appreciate it!